# How to assign relation when working with pivot table in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

### Details

I have 3 tables :

- catalog_downloads
- export_frequencies
- export_frequencies_catalog_downloads (Pivot Table)

### Diagram

[image]

I am not sure if I set the relation between them correctly.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

### Here is what I did

In `CatalogDownload.php`

```
public function export_frequencies(){ 
        return $this->belongsToMany('ExportFrequency','export_frequencies_catalog_downloads','export_frequency_id','catalog_download_id');
    }
```

In `ExportFrequency.php`

```
public function catalog_downloads(){ 
        return $this->belongsToMany('CatalogDownload','export_frequencies_catalog_downloads','export_frequency_id','catalog_download_id');
    }
```

### Questions

- According to my diagram - Did I assign the relationship correctly ? 
  I hope I didn't mix up between `hasMany` and `belongsTo`
- Will I need a class or a model for a Pivot Table ?

Thanks

Comment: since you don't have additional content in your pivot table you don't need a model for the pivot table. Eloquent has a basic pivot model built in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Did assign my relation properly ?

Comment: I think so. don't see a problem there. did you try it out?

Comment: ahh wait there is a problem

Comment: the id's in export_frequencies should be switched. the first id is the id of the 'local' object (catalogdownload in that case) and the second id is the id of the referenced object (exportfrequency in that case)

Comment: I swap them now, thanks again for the second tip. You should put together the answer for this, and I will make sure to accept it. It'll be useful for community. What do you think ? It seem like you answered both of my questions.

Comment: Added a somewhat extended answer that goes a bit deeper than you asked

Comment: Precisely. You're awesome @ITroubs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `export_frequencies` is in the `CatalogDownload` model you have to invert the ID's because the parameters of belongsToMany are as follows:

```
1. Name of the referenced (target) Model (ExportFrequency)
2. Name of the Pivot table
3. Name of the id colum of the referencing (local) Model (CatalogDownload in this case)
4. Name of the id colum of the referenced (target) Model (ExportFrequency in this case)
```

what leads to this function:

```
public function export_frequencies(){ 

        return $this->belongsToMany('ExportFrequency','export_frequencies_catalog_downloads','export_frequency_id','catalog_download_id');
    }
```

The other function was correct.

If you had some data in your pivot table, for instance a colum with the name `someCounter` then you will have to tell the relation to load that column when creating the pivot object like this:

```
public function export_frequencies(){ 

        return $this->belongsToMany('ExportFrequency','export_frequencies_catalog_downloads','export_frequency_id','catalog_download_id')->withPivot('someCounter');
}
```

That will load the column and make it avalible like this:

```
$catalogDownload->export_frequencies()->first()->pivot->someCounter;
```

You will need a separate Pivot Model if you need to do some special handling for the fields or if that pivot itself has a relation of its own but then you might consider using a full blown model instead of a pure Pivot Model.

Answer (score 1):

As an added note to the accepted answer, you are able to set up your many to many relationships without referencing the pivot table and the relevant id's as long as you follow a specific convention.

You can name your pivot table using singular references to the related tables, like '**catalog_download_export_frequency**'. **Notice the alphabetic order of the singular references**.

Then you can simply do:

```
// CatalogDownload Model
public function exportFrequencies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('ExportFrequency');
}

// ExportFrequency Model
public function catalogDownloads()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('CatalogDownload');
}
```

This will then allow you to run queries using the query builder or Eloquent like:

```
$catalogDownload->exportFrequencies()->get(); // Get all export frequencies for a specific CatalogDownload.
```

Or

```
$this->catalogDownload->with('exportFrequencies')->find($id); // Using eager loading and dependency injection, when CatalogDownload is assigned to $this->catalogDownload
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I also like your solution. Thanks mate :D